# ZF2 - get router configuration array

Tags: php, zend-framework2

in ZF2 we config routing in module.config.php like this:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/admin[/:action][/:id][/:page]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9a-zA-Z]+',
                    'page' => 'page\-[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Is it possible to access elements of this array in for example view helper or controller? If it is how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller you can get it from the service locator:

```
$serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator();
$config = $serviceLocator->get("config");
$router = $config["router"];
```

To access it from a view, you can create a View Helper like this:

1.**ConfigHelper** class:

```
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;  
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface; 

//IT NEEDS TO IMPLEMENT ServiceLocatorAwareInterface IN ORDER TO USE THE ServiceLocator
class ConfigHelper extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    private $config, $helperPluginManager, $serviceManager;

    public function getConfig() {
        if ( !isset( $this->config ) ) {
            $this->config = $this->serviceManager->get( 'config' );
        }

        return $this->config;
    }

    /** 
     * Set the service locator. 
     * 
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator 
     * @return CustomHelper 
     */  
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator; 

        return $this;  
    }

    /**
     * Get the service locator.
     *
     * @return \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface
     */
    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function __invoke() {
        if ( !isset( $this->helperPluginManager ) || !isset( $this->serviceManager ) ) {
            $this->helperPluginManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
            //USING THE ServiceLocator YOU CAN GET THE serviceManager NEEDED TO GET THE CONFIG ARRAY
            $this->serviceManager = $this->helperPluginManager->getServiceLocator(); 
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

2.**Module** class:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'confighelper' => '<NAMESPACE>\ConfigHelper',
        ),
    );
}
```

3.**view** template:

```
$config = $this->configHelper()->getConfig();
$router = $config["router"];
```